# fileinputstream throwing filenotfoundexception?

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I'm trying to open up an xml file to parse it, but I am getting stopped trying to open the file. My code is:

```
        try {
            return new FileInputStream(location);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

where location is a String passed into the function. Upon running my code, I get:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /C:/Users/Seth/AndroidWorkspace/UCoupon/res/xml/information.xml (No such file or directory)

I gave the full file path, and I havn't mispelled anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't read files on your pc from your device or emulator.

see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for an introduction to Data Storage and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) for Accessing Resources (that is probably what you're interested in, as you're trying to access `res/xml/`)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load a file using the real path on your PC. Emulator knows nothing about your file system.

When you put an xml into the project folder `res/xml/` you can parse it using the standar resource lookup way:

`XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);`
where myxml is the name of your xml file without the extension

Comment: I looked into that but couldn't understand how it fits in with the code I have. I implemented a custom xml parser much like the 8th example here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html I am trying to write the method getInputStream() so that I can use the line "Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());"

Comment: In the article, the xml file is downloaded from the net. so this is not 
your case. The method `Resource.getXml()` returns a reference to a 
`XmlResourceParser` object. The article covers this case at the section 
"The XML pull parser". `XmlResourceParser` and `XmlPullParser` uses the same interface

Answer (score 0):

You can not access files from your host system (which seems to be Windows in your case). Copy the file to your devices/emulators SD card and read it from there - and don't forget to use the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.